# How to explain to those singing along that they interfere/obstruct/? the choir?

Tags: word-usage

Say, there is a small choir singing.
Some people outside of choir out of their ignorance thinking they gonna help start singing along (usually out of tune and even not seeing the conductor).
Leaving all musical and social aspects away, how a conductor can explain them in the most direct way and plain English that their singing along is completely opposite of helping for singers and ruins the performance?

> "Your singing along distracts the choir? impedes/hinders/interferes?
>   Ruins our efforts?"

I am struggling to find the right verb here as there are not many examples around.. Thanks!

Comment: If it's a *professional* setting, only the members of the choir should be singing anyway, *regardless* of how well people outside the choir might (or might not) sing. (If somebody has a really great voice, they can be invited to join the choir if they wish.) Nobody outside of actors are allowed to speak on a film set when a scene is being shot. This is exactly the same. No film set has any director say, "you're distracting the actors." Instead, there are simply signs that read *quiet on set*, and anybody who is not quiet is escorted out.

Comment: Sadly, not all people understand that. Though that particular setting is not professional (i.e. singers do not have formal diplomas in music), yet people in the choir put their efforts in rehearsals and preparation for the event. No matter how great someone's voice is, it is is hard for them to make valuable contribution to the choir without rehearsing together.
Anyway, the purpose of my question was - how to word my intent to tell these people to not distract us from singing, so they understand it does not help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question includes an element about vocabulary and about appropriate ways to ask the audience not to sing along. Possibilities for vocabulary include: compete, disrupt, distract, detract, and interfere. These are not necessarily good word choices for instructing the audience.

In a formal or informal setting, something like "please keep quiet during the performance" or "please turn off your phone, keep quiet, and refrain from singing along during the performance" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There are no magic words, you just ask politely.

> Please don't sing along with the choir.

I fact there would normally be a lot of "fluff" around this.

> Hello everyone and welcome to our recital.  I'd like to thank you all for coming and remind you that flash photography does distract our singers so please refrain from it. Also, the choir has been practising hard this term and I'm sure we all want to hear them sing, so if I can ask everyone not to sing along with them, as this can also be distracting. Now without further ado let's move onto the first item...

Whether you say "distracts" or "hinders" doesn't really matter, it is just part of the "fluff".